# Error in SQL when doing a datediff

Tags: date, type-conversion

I am getting the below error in SQL server 2012, when trying to do a datediff to get number of days between two date columns.

I am trying the below where `createdts` is `varchar` and I have converted today's date to show date in `varchar`. Why does it not still work?

```
DATEDIFF(day, Load_Confirmed.createdts, CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE(), 104))
```

> ERROR- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your createdts column should be converted into datetime datatype before you can use the datediff function to find difference between 2 dates.

```
create table #tempdate
(
createdts varchar(30)
)

insert into #tempdate(createdts) values ('2017-09-19')

select DATEDIFF(hour,convert(date,createdts,120),getdate()) from #tempdate
```

Comment: I don't have permissions to create table

Comment: You don't have to create table, just use the select statement i have given and it should work.